# How much charge is moved for one heart beat?

Tags: neuroscience, cardiology, action-potential, electrocardiography

Roughly, how much charge cycles (in and out of our heart cells) for each heart beat?

I am just looking for the total number of Coulombs, but, since all charge can
[apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardiac_action_potential) be
accounted for with just $Na^+$, $K^+$, $Cl^-$, and $Ca^{2+}$ itemization,
it would be great if you can break it down by these ions.

My crude estimation comes from some $1\mu F/cm^2$ neuron wall capacitance
references, my guessed $10cm^2$ wall area (though the heart is bigger, I just
want the neurons), and the often-quoted $70mV$ action potential.  This gives $0.7\mu C$
(which is 4 trillion singly-charged ions).  But, I suspect that the true value
is much higher based on some other animal neuron papers that I found.

Comment: Most of the heart's electrical activity is in muscles, not neurons.

Comment: @BryanKrause I might have used the term "neuron" too loosely.  I am actually interested in all of the heart's electrical activity which factors into ECG waveforms.  So, feel free to change "neuron" to "muscle" in my question (unless the electrical activity you mention somehow gets muted in ECG data...and then it would of course be nice to explain the cause for this muting in any answer).

Comment: That's going to be quite the venture... the physics are incredibly complex, because while you generate voltages across membranes, these voltages are aligned in all sorts of directions and the vast majority cancel each other out when measured at a distance. Why do you need or want to know this? The reason you can measure an EKG at distance is because of spatial organization in the depolarizaton/repolarization of the heart: the top goes first. Bit of that discussed here: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/90434/in-the-pr-segment-of-an-ecg-how-come-theres-no-current-flowing/90492#90492

Comment: See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @BryanKrause My question did not ask about the full EKG interpretation because I know it's complex.  I just want to know the total charge that goes through neuron/muscle membranes in the heart for each heart beat (not the directions you point out...it seems like you are pushing this into an xy problem).

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why you need this information, though; what do you plan to do with it? That's the XY part. Since you mentioned you were interested in EKG, it seems relevant that answering the question as asked won't really tell you anything about EKG measurement.